# Capture first value of event.clientX/Y with a mousemove listener

Tags: javascript, events

I'm tracking the mouse curse with an event listener

```
window.addEventListener('mousemove', function);
```

I want to measure the distance from the position the cursor was at when the event listener is instantiated (via a separate 'click' event) to it's current position. To this end, I've tried capturing the the event.clientX and event.clientY positions at the start of the event and assigning them to variables

```
originX = event.clientX
originY = event.clientY
```

However, these reference the .clientX/Y positions, so these variables change on every mousemove event. How can I capture the first value of the event.clientX/Y so I can calculate the delta?

Comment: Declare `originX/Y` in an outer scope, and assign the first values in the click handler. Then in `mousemove` handler assign `clientX/Y` to `originX/Y` just before leaving the function.

Comment: thanks, that did it!